# If to compare two dates using Carbon on Laravel, a date from a table and a now() instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, php-carbon

I'm trying to display some items from a table and I'm ordering by the time they begin, I only want to show the next three items starting from now(). Here is my controller function:

Probably the whole thing is completely wrong, but still, any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
  public function next(Request $request)
    {

          $eventos = Event::orderBy('start','asc');
          $eventTime = Carbon::createFromDate($eventos->start);
          $mytime = Carbon::now();

          if($eventTime > $mytime){

          $eventos = paginate(3);

          return view('evento.next',compact('eventos'));
        }

    }
```

Comment: In what way does this fail to do what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public function next(Request $request)
    {
      $eventos=Event::where('start','>=',Carbon::now()) // select all recodrs where start Time more than now date
                  ->orderBy('start','asc')  // order all records by asc
                  ->take(3)                // take first 3 record
                  ->get();                // now get the result

              return view('evento.next',compact('eventos'));
     }
```